# How to rewrite /file/(name) to /q.html?id=(name) in NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

For example, rewriting /file/example to /q.html?id=example or /file/test to /q.html?id=test using NGINX.

How would that look like?

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/file/(.+)$ /q.html?id=$1 redirect;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways of preforming an external redirect in Nginx, but the simplest solution would be:

```
rewrite ^/file/(.+)$ /q.html?id=$1 redirect;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.